# Found an unexpected Mach-o Header code:0x72613c21 xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, mongodb, react-native, xcode9.2

First of all, I am new to xCode and have developed iOS app which has already been working in Android perfectly. But when I convert the same into Xcode, I found so many error that I removed myself gradually.

My problem is that I add the project in Xcode, add reference library
 etc and build the project. after so many error, finally my build start and end at `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`. Afterward, I start archiving the project and it completed but when I export it shows me `Found an unexpected Mach-o header code`. I google it and found so many solution but all in vain.

> Critical.log 2018-06-18 17:15:43 +0000  Failed to generate
>   distribution items with error: Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0
>   "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found an unexpected Mach-O header
>   code: 0x72613c21, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}
>
> Standard.log2018-06-18 17:15:37 +0000 [MT] Beginning distribution
>   assistant for archive: kRide, task: Export 2018-06-18 17:15:42 +0000
>   [MT] Proceeding to distribution step
>   IDEDistributionAnalyzeArchiveStepViewController, context:
>   ',
>   distributionTask(resolved)='2',
>   distributionMethod(resolved)='', team(resolved)='(null)'>    Chain (3, self inclusive):
>     ',
>   distributionMethod='', team='(null)'>  ',
>   distributionMethod='', team='(null)'>  ',
>   distributionMethod='(null)', team='(null)'>

Please suggest me where I am wrong and what I need to do to export the project to have .ipa file

Answer (score 0):

try to **DELETE BUILD** folder from **IOS directory and rebuild again** with
**react-native run-ios**

Comment: I did so many things but all in vain. I did the same but same error.

Comment: ohh..remove the IOS folder and do react-native upgrade